# Concept question about the number of firestore real-time listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to minimize the number of firestore listeners when I paginate data. Im using the firestore webv9 but that doesn't matter here. My question is..

Every time I call this function aren't I creating a new listener? If so how can I combine or reuse the listener or snapshot so I only have one listener even if I call this function 1000 times?!

```
async getPaginatedData_RTL(queryParams: TQueryParams, onChange: Function){

let collectionReference = collection(firestore, queryParams.pathToDataInCollection);

const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collectionReferenceQuery, (snapshot: QuerySnapshot) => {
  onChange(snapshot);
})

this.unsubscriptions.push(unsubscribe)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "combine or reuse"?  Either you are creating a new listener using onSnapshot, or you are not.  Without knowing what you intend to do with these listeners and the data behind them, there's not much we can do to help.  The question is too abstract.  If you want to create fewer listeners, just call onSnapshot less often.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, I've updated the question so I hope it's clearer.  Basically, I want just one listener to keep extending the number of documents it is listening to so I'm not creating new listeners each time(scales poorly) and stressing my backend if I have a lot of users.

Comment: If you just want one listener, then just create one listener.  Is that not possible?  Where are you stuck with that?  I still don't understand the nature of the problem.  All you have here is a function without no context on how you intend to use it.

Comment: Im not "stuck" with that - Im not an idiot. Ive repeatedly mentioned I want to call this class several times to get new paginated data and I dont want to create a new listener each time. If the average user gets a lot of paginated data they will have lots of listeners. In my own testing Ive had upwards of 30 listeners and 15 active at one time for 1 or 2 chats. Now scale that for 100, 1000, 1 million users who have 10-15 chats each.

Comment: Everything you just said is excellent context to have in the question itself, so we can better understand the problem at hand.  It sounds like you're trying to combine pagination with realtime updates, and there's really no easy way to do that.  Typically you choose one or the other.  If you want both, you're going to end up with a lot of listeners, and there's no way around it.

Comment: Ive actually created a wrapper that can handle real-time new messages and real-time paginated messages with full edit/delete capabilities for everything. Works very well. Im thinking about throwing up a gist. In any case Ill keep an eye on this to see if there is some better way to minimize my number of listeners

Comment: @Leon If you already found a solution, can you please post it as an answer for visibility ?

Comment: Hi @RajeevTirumalasetty, I have not found an answer for how to keep a low number of listeners while expanding the number of documents/collections I am listening to